# Magento 2 - How to write data to window.checkoutConfig from PHP?

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, configuration

I created a new shippping method, I need to generate data and pass it to the `window.checkoutConfig` javascript object.

Normally you do this by implementing the **ConfigProviderInterface** from **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ConfigProviderInterface.php**, but this only works if the data already exist and you just have to write it into the $config.

I need to generate the data during runtime while I am generating the shipping method. The data is simply a HTML code.

How can I write the data into the config, so that it is available under `window.checkoutConfig.express_note`?

Shipping Method:

**MODULE/Model/Carrier/Express.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Express extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{

    protected $_code = 'express';

    protected $_isFixed = true;

    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $note = "<div>dynamically generated html code</div>";    // How to make this data available under window.checkoutConfig.express_note ?

        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * getAllowedMethods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing the **ConfigProviderInterface** from **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ConfigProviderInterface.php** and moving the generation code to my plugin.

**Company/Shipping/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="company_shipping_configprovider" xsi:type="object">Company\Shipping\Model\Config\Express</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Company/Shipping/Model/Config/Express.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Shipping\Model\Config;

class Express implements \Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dynamicHtml;

    public function __construct(
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->rule = $this->createDynamicHtml();
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];
        $config['dynamicHtml'] = $this->dynamicHtml;
        return $config;
    }

    public function getDynamicHtml()
    {
        return $this->dynamicHtml;
    }

    public function createDynamicHtml()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Then in the carrier collectRates method I am fetching the value from the dynamic generated html.

**Company/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Express.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Express extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{

    ...

    protected $_expressSettingsFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Company\Shipping\Model\Config\ExpressFactory $expressSettingsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = [],
        \Company\Shipping\Model\Config\ExpressFactory $expressSettingsFactory
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->_expressSettingsFactory = $expressSettingsFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Company\Shipping\Model\Config\Express $expressSettings */
        $expressSettings = $this->_expressSettingsFactory->create();

        $note = $expressSettings->getDynamicHtml();

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it in script ?

```
$note = "<div>dynamically generated html code</div>"
$note.="<script>window.checkoutConfig.express_note = <?php YOUR_CONTENT_VALUE ?></script>";
```

So as when your note will be append to the html, the script will be sent too and the variable will be set.

Comment: But the method `collectRates` does not return $html so how should this work?

Comment: Yeah you right. I guess this is for this kind of situation we need knockoutjs, but this is out of my skills sorry. A bad way of doing things would be to setup something like a cookie in your php method and then try to assign the checkoutConfig by reading these cookie.

Comment: No knockoutjs is just a template engine, it does not help me to add data from PHP to the window object. Using cookies would be a good workaround. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: When you are bad at the game you start searching for cheatcode :D Hope it will help.